# Configure Oracle 11.2+ ACL to work with mail server having an internal IP address

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

I configured a new Oracle 11.2.0.4 database on CentOS 7.

I verified that I can send email from the database server 192.168.0.1's linux command line, using an 192.168.0.2 mail server (e.g. mail.example.com) on port 26.

The `/etc/hosts` file on the database server (192.168.0.1) contains the line

```
192.168.0.2 host9.example.com mail.example.com
```

so the database server can map `mail.example.com` to 192.168.0.2.

I'm trying to send mail using the following command in SQLDeveloper worksheet for schema1,

`exec utl_mail.send(sender => 'name@example.com', recipients => 'name@example.com', subject => 'My Title', message => 'my body');`

and it works. Then I use the same command minus the `exec` in a function called by a stored procedure, both in schema1, and it gives error

```
stack trace: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-24247: network access denied by access control list (ACL)
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_MAIL", line 662
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_MAIL", line 679
ORA-06512: at "SCHEMA1.MY_FUNC", line 260
ORA-06512: at "SCHEMA1.MY_PROC", line 40
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

My configuration is as follows. If I `select * from dba_network_acls;` as SYS I get:

```
192.168.0.2 26  26  /sys/acls/http_permissions.xml 3948232AFFA4833B3938204804923F39
192.168.0.2 443 443 /sys/acls/http_permissions.xml 3948232AFFA4833B3938204804923F39
192.168.0.2 80  80  /sys/acls/http_permissions.xml 3948232AFFA4833B3938204804923F39
192.168.0.2 25  25  /sys/acls/http_permissions.xml 3948232AFFA4833B3938204804923F39
```

If I `SELECT acl, principal, privilege, is_grant, TO_CHAR(start_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY') AS start_date, TO_CHAR(end_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY') AS end_date FROM dba_network_acl_privileges;` as SYS I get:

```
/sys/acls/http_permissions.xml  SCHEMA1 connect true    13-JAN-2017 
/sys/acls/http_permissions.xml  SCHEMA1 resolve true    13-JAN-2017
```

If I `select * from V$PARAMETER where NAME = 'smtp_out_server'` as SYS I get;

`3314   smtp_out_server 2   mail.example.com      mail.example.com  FALSE   TRUE    IMMEDIATE   TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   utl_smtp server and port configuration parameter        3948483925`

If instead I use a proven mail package from 11.2.0.1 to send mail via `UTL_SMTP` in schema1, it fails with `ORA-24247: network access denied by access control list (ACL)` from both SQLDeveloper and function `SCHEMA1.MY_FUNC`. It fails on this line:

```
mail_conn := utl_smtp.open_connection('mail.example.com', 26);
```

Any idea what could be wrong?

UPDATE

If I replace `mail.example.com` with `192.168.0.2` when setting `smtp_out_server` so that `select * from V$PARAMETER where NAME = 'smtp_out_server'` returns

`3314   smtp_out_server 2   192.168.0.2   192.168.0.2   FALSE   TRUE    IMMEDIATE   TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   utl_smtp server and port configuration parameter        3948483925`

then the `UTL_MAIL.SEND` command from both SQLDeveloper worksheet and function give the error `ORA-29279: SMTP permanent error: 550 Access denied - Invalid HELO name (See RFC2821 4.1.3)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I finally (!) got to work. Simply set `smtp_out_server` equal to `mail.example.com`, then add `mail.example.com` to the ACL using, from SQLDeveloper:

```
-- leave <lower|upper>_port null to allow access to all ports
exec dbms_network_acl_admin.assign_acl (acl => 'http_permissions.xml', host => '*.example.com'); 
commit;
```

Notice above that I used `*.example.com` instead of `mail.example.com` because doing it this way also allows UTL_HTTP requests to `www.example.com` (kill 2 birds with one stone). Also, by not specifying upper and lower port bounds, we enable access for all ports. If you want, you can specify the exact ports as done in the original posting above.

Here's the `UTL_SMTP` related code:

```
g_mail_conn := UTL_SMTP.OPEN_CONNECTION('mail.example.com', 26);
UTL_SMTP.EHLO(g_mail_conn, 'mail.example.com');
UTL_SMTP.MAIL(g_mail_conn, p_sender_email);
...
```

Note that I'm using port 26 for SMTP, whereas most of the world uses port 25 (so just update your code accordingly). Also, there's no authentication (e.g. username/password) for the non-SSL port (26; no need, since I'm using an internal IP address).

The UTL_MAIL command also works from SQLDeveloper:

```
exec utl_mail.send(sender => 'name1@example.com', recipients => 'name2@example.com', message => 'Hi there');
```